# Python: Import custom module in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to import a module that I created in Google Colab and use the functions therein in another module.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/importing-your-own-python-module-or-python-file-into-colab-3e365f0a35ec) which seems similar to other instructions, and have the following code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import sys
sys.path.append('/content/drive/MyDrive/python_scripts/')

import myscript
dir(myscript)
```

I'm unable, however, to see the functions I created, and instead just see the following

```
['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__']
```

I can't, then, access any of the functions within this module.

I've also created an `__init__py` file in the relevant folder, but that hasn't seemed to help.

Any ideas would be great!

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: Copy your modules to /content. Your current approach doesn't work, because `__init__` should in every folder on path from /content to your modules path to be accesible from notebook

Comment: Hi @gimme_danger. Thanks for the response. So, just checking, the `/content` folder, is that just the MyDrive root? Because I've actually added an `__init__.py` in each folder from there onwards

Comment: Hi @Mike, I summarize my thoughts into an answer

Answer (score 1):

`/content` folder is a current working directory for Colab notebook execution and I recommend you to copy your scripts repo to `/content`:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!cp -r /content/drive/MyDrive/python_scripts /content

from python_scripts.myscript import smth
smth()
```

Alternative approach would be adding `__init__.py` on path from `/content` to your folder. But I found that `/content/drive` is read-only, so you cannot add `__init__.py` there and this "solution" couldn't work:

```
!cp -rv $path/__init__.py /content/drive
> '/content/drive/MyDrive/script_folder/__init__.py' -> '/content/drive/__init__.py'
> cp: cannot create regular file '/content/drive/__init__.py': Operation not supported
```

Comment: Thank you! Not in front of my pc now, but I’ll give that a try, sounds like it’ll work perfectly!

If you don’t mind two follow up questions:
1) how do I navigate to that location through my browser
2) could I just change my working directory to be where the files are?

Thanks  again!

Comment: 1) You could navigate through file system with interface on the left;

Comment: 2) Use regular linux commands directly in Colub cells: `cd` to move to another folder, `ls` to show the content of current folder, etc